# Nested resource controllers and routes with ajax

Tags: php, laravel, dropdown

I used the following code for `web.php`.

```
Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
Route::resource('products.galleries', 'GalleryController');
```

In this address http://localhost:8000/admin/products , I added this code

```
<td><a href="{{ route('products.galleries.create', $product->id) }}">Create</a></td>
```

Then I defined it in `create` method, and control of `GalleryController`

GalleryController.php

```
public function create(Product $product)
{
    return view('Admin.galleries.create', compact('product'));
}
```

**The gallery is empty**

I am using **dropdown**

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{{ route('products.galleries.destroy', [$product->id, $gallery->id]) }}',
    date: {filename, name},
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('File has been successfully removed!!');
    },
    error: function (e){
        console.log(e);
    },
});
```

I get this error

> Undefined variable: gallery

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `GalleryController`, a gallery instance (`$gallery`) is never sent to the view:

```php
public function create(Product $product)
{
    return view('Admin.galleries.create', compact('product')); // where is $gallery ?
}
```

This is why in your view, when you are trying to use `$gallery` (in your javascript, the destroy route), you get an error.

You have multiple ways to fix this, depending on what you are exactly trying to achieve. However, without more information, the fastest solution would be to wrap your javascript code inside a condition.

```js
@isset($gallery)
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{{ route('products.galleries.destroy', [$product->id, $gallery->id]) }}',
        date: {filename, name},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('File has been successfully removed!!');
        },
        error: function (e){
            console.log(e);
        },
    });
@endisset
```

I presume you did it this way because you want to reuse this part of the view when a `$gallery` variable is available, for instance `products.galleries.index` or `products.galleries.show`.

By wrapping the javascript in `@isset($gallery)` tags, you'll ensure it will only be executed when a `$gallery` instance is available.

Answer (score 0):

The issues is simple because there is no definition for `$gallery` variable in the `url` part of ajax.

Can you explain what is the purpose of `$gallery` variable in the `destroy` route and how you are passing it to the `create` blade.